# Автоматический вход на сайт после регистрации

Tags: php

Всем привет, я уже реализовал модуль регистрации и модуль входа на сайт на своем проекте, но не могу сделать так, чтобы после регистрации пользователь автоматически входил на сайт. Помогите, пожалуйста, как мне это лучше реализовать? Пишу сайт на PHP, вход на сайт осуществляется с помощью сессий.

```
registration.php
<?php
    header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
    header('Content-type: text/html');

    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    $title = "Регистрация";

    require_once('header.php');

    //инициализирум механизм сесссий
    session_start(); 
    #echo (session_id()); #отладка
    #echo("<br>");
?>  
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function (){
            $("#create_account").submit(function(e){
                var email = $("#email").val();
                alert(!!email.match(/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,4})+$/));
                //e.preventDefault();
            });
        });
    </script>
    <section id="middle" class="group">
        <div id="container">
            <div id="content">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <form id="create_account" action="registration_new.php" method="POST">
                        <fieldset id="singup">
                            <legend>Создайте новый аккаунт</legend>
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <label for="username"><i class="icon-user"></i>Логин:</label>
                                    <input id="username" type="text" autofocus name="username" placeholder="John" tabindex="1">
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <label for="email"><i class="icon-envelope"></i>Email:</label>
                                    <input id="email" type="text" name="email" placeholder="user@example.com" autocomplete="off" tabindex="2">
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <label for="password"><i class="icon-question-sign"></i>Пароль:</label>
                                    <input id="password" type="password" name="password" value="" autocomplete="off" placeholder="8-10 символов" tabindex="3">
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <label for="password_confirm"><i class="icon-question-sign"></i>Повторите пароль:</label>
                                    <input id="password_confirm" type="password" name="password_confirm" value="" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Введите пароль еще раз" tabindex="4">
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <button class="btn btn-primary" tabindex="5"><span><i class="icon-ok icon-white"></i></span>Зарегистрироваться</button>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </fieldset>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div><!-- #content-->
        </div><!-- #container-->
        <aside id="sideRight">
            <p>Зарегистрируйтесь, чтобы стать полноценным участником сервиса. Вы сможете голосовать, участвовать в рейтинге и использовать личные сообщения для общения с другими пользователями.</p>
        </aside><!-- #sideRight -->
    </section><!-- #middle-->
<?php
    require_once('footer.php');
?>

registration_new.php

<?php
    header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
    header('Content-type: text/html');

    $title = "Регистрация прошла успешно!";

    require_once("header.php");

    //Подключение к БД
    require_once("mysql.php");

    #echo (session_id()); #отладка
    #echo("<br>");

    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    //Создать короткие имена переменных
    $username = trim(strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['username']))); #login
    $email = trim(strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']))); 
    $password = trim(strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['password'])));
    $password_confirm = trim(strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['password_confirm'])));
    $date = date("d-m-Y H:i:s"); //Дата регистрации пользователя, чтобы можно было посчитать сколько дней и часов участник на сайте. Например - На сайте: 22 дня 13 часов.

    echo $date;

    //Проверка e-mail с помощью php (на стороне сервера)
    function validateEmail($email)
    {
        $pattern = "/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,4})+$/";
        if(!preg_match($pattern, $email)) 
        {
            return die("<br>Введите корректный email адрес.<br>");
        }
    }

    echo validateEmail($email);

    if($password === $password_confirm)
    {
        $query = "INSERT INTO users (id, username, email, password, `date`)
                VALUES(0, '$username', '$email', SHA1('$password'), NOW())";
        $result = mysql_unbuffered_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

        mysql_free_result($result);
        mysql_close($conn);

        echo("<div class=\"alert alert-success\">");
        echo("<h1>Регистрация прошла успешно!</h1><hr>\n");
        echo("<h2>Письмо с регистрационными данными было отправлено\n Вам на email - $email</h2>\n");
        echo("<p>Проверьте свою электронную почту, чтобы завершить регистрацию.</p>\n");
        echo("<p>Если письмо не придет на Ваш почтовый ящик в течении 15 минут после регистрации, проверьте, пожалуйста, папку \"Спам\".</p>\n");
        echo("<p>Если письмо от нашего сервиса попало в папку \"Спам\", отметьте его как не спам и, пожалуйста, добавьте на электронный адрес <span>add@askdev.ru</span> в Вашу адресную книгу.\n");
        echo("</div>");
    }
    else
    {
        echo("<div class=\"alert alert-error\">");
        echo("<p>Введите пароль еще раз!</p>\n");
        echo("</div>");
    }

    require_once("footer.php");
?>

login.php
<?php
    header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
    header('Content-type: text/html');

    $title = "Вход на сайт";

    require_once('header.php');

    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    $login = trim(strip_tags($_POST['login']));
    $password = sha1($_POST['password']);

    //Подключение к БД
    require_once("mysql.php");

    $sql = "SELECT username, password FROM users WHERE username='$login' AND password='$password'"; # JOIN SELECT password FROM users WHERE password='$password'
    $result = mysql_unbuffered_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    $result = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    if(($login == $result['username']) && ($password == $result['password']))
    {
        #header("Location: index.php");
        echo("<div class=\"alert alert-success\">");
        echo("<p>Логин и пароль совпадают!!! Добро пожаловать на сайт <b>$login</b></p>");
        echo("</div>");
    }
    else
    {
        echo("<div class=\"alert alert-error\">");
        echo("<p>Такая комбинация логина и пароля не найдена. Повторите попытку снова.</p>");
        echo("</div>");
    }

    $_SESSION['username'] = $result['username'];
    $_SESSION['password'] = $result['password'];

    foreach($_SESSION as $item)
    {
        echo "$item<br>";
    }
    echo (session_id()); #отладка
    echo("<br>"); #отладка
    echo("Добро пожаловать на сайт ".$_SESSION['username']); #отладка
    echo("<br>"); #отладка
    //КОНЕЦ инициализации механизма сессий!!!

    mysql_free_result($result);
    mysql_close($conn);
?>
    <section id="middle" class="group">
        <div id="container">
            <div id="content">
                <div class="container">
                    <form id="login" action="login.php" method="POST">
                        <fieldset>
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <label for="login"><i class="icon-user"></i>Логин:</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="login">
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <label for="password"><i class="icon-question-sign"></i>Пароль:</label>
                                    <input type="password" name="password">
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <button class="btn btn-primary"><span><i class="icon-hand-up icon-white"></i>Войти</button>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </fieldset>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="container">
                    <form action="logout.php" method="POST">
                        <fieldset>
                            <button class="btn btn-danger"><span><i class="icon-off icon-white"></i>Выйти</button>
                        </fieldset>
                    </form> 
                    <a class="btn btn-danger" href="logout.php">Выход</a>
                </div>
            </div><!-- #content-->
        </div><!-- #container-->
        <aside id="sideRight">
            <p>Приветствуем Вас на сайте...</p>
        </aside><!-- #sideRight -->
    </section><!-- #middle-->
<?php
    require_once('footer.php');
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

registration_new.php:

```
...
$_SESSIOIN['username'] = $username;
$_SESSION['password'] = sha1($password);

echo("<div class=\"alert alert-success\">");
```

Comment: Мне нужно его как-то отправить через POST в файл login.php. А как это сделать не ясно(

Comment: Код добавил!

Answer (score 3):

Сударь вы знаете толк в извращениях

```
        echo("<div class=\"alert alert-success\">");
        echo("<h1>Регистрация прошла успешно!</h1><hr>\n");
        echo("<h2>Письмо с регистрационными данными было отправлено\n Вам на email - $email</h2>\n");
        echo("<p>Проверьте свою электронную почту, чтобы завершить регистрацию.</p>\n");
        echo("<p>Если письмо не придет на Ваш почтовый ящик в течении 15 минут после регистрации, проверьте, пожалуйста, папку \"Спам\".</p>\n");
        echo("<p>Если письмо от нашего сервиса попало в папку \"Спам\", отметьте его как не спам и, пожалуйста, добавьте на электронный адрес <span>add@askdev.ru</span> в Вашу адресную книгу.\n");
        echo("</div>");
    }
    else
    {
        echo("<div class=\"alert alert-error\">");
        echo("<p>Введите пароль еще раз!</p>\n");
        echo("</div>");
```

Один раз вывести все разом нельзя? Нет ну я так к слову, раз уж помочь так и по оптимизации тут можно изменить код.

Comment: на крайняк `echo ("1"),("2"),("3");`

Comment: ну как один из вариантов

Comment: Спасибо, буду улучшать код, всем спасибо за ответы!

Answer (score 0):

Пусть будет не в обиду сказано, но такой код надо цитировать на сайте govnokod.ru

Повторная авторизация организуется через куку. В куку пишется в простейшем случае, что пользователь уже авторизиорван. Но, такую куку легко подделать, по этому в куку дополнительно записывают некий токен, например crc32($userId + 42 + time); где 42 - есть некоторое ничего не значищее секретное число и куку time.

Далее, при авторизации проверяется наличие кук кука userId , подлинность куки  Token & time:
По userId вытаскиваем профиль юзера, в случае если совпадает равенство: 
сrc32(  userId из куки + 42 + time из куки ) = token из куки.

Не зная числа 42, и при постоянно  изменяющимся time  подделать куку практически невозможно. При этом time может быть не unixtime, а например microtime() или иное случайное число.  Я обычно использую expireTime, одной кукой убиваю лвух зайцев.

Если равенства нет - следовательно с куками проблемы - юзера в сад, т.е. на страницу авторизации.

Куку ставлю на год, но при каждом новом заходе пользователя ее перегенерю.